# Can the ~てくれてありがとう form be used to thank someone for more general actions?

Tags: usage

If I would like to thank someone for their work (in the context of "wow! what a lovely sculpture! thank you for your effort/for letting us see this!" or "thank you for writing about this subject, it's pretty obscure!"), would the ~てくれて form still be the best choice to express this? From what I know so far, あげる/くれる/もらう are used for a pretty of personal level of giving and receiving, but I of course don't want my thanks to imply the person created whatever they did specifically for me (or for anyone but themselves, really!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to thank someone you don't know personally for their work, you can use "-していただきありがとうございます", honorifics in Japanese to express psychological distance and respect at the same time.

This kind of honorific means to express your gratitude; "I have so much respect for you because I can't do something so amazing like you can! You are an amazing person in a very high place compared to me!"